# Should the NGXS NgxsLoggerPluginModule be removed for production builds?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, ngxs

During development we usually use the imports:

```
import { NgxsReduxDevtoolsPluginModule } from '@ngxs/devtools-plugin';
import { NgxsLoggerPluginModule } from '@ngxs/logger-plugin';
```

Should these be removed for production builds or is there benefit to keeping these intact with the production build (Troubleshooting production issues ...?)

Comment: You usually remove such Plugins in prod env. It only consumes memory and doesn't give your customer a benefit.
You can keep them in QA and DEV

Comment: That's what I figured.  Would be neat if the modules had a flag that would could notify the compiler to not include them in the production build.

Comment: actually there is a opportunity to include the module depending on the production flag inside your environment.ts

Comment: Oh so we can exclude the module from production in environments.ts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will sum up my comments for you in this answer:

You usually remove such Plugins in `prod` env. 
It only consumes **memory** and doesn't give your customer a **benefit**. You can keep them in QA and DEV, at least, this is how I do it.

Here is how I can handle it in my builds:

```
// Module
// example with ngrx, but it works the same with ngxs
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    ...,
    environment.devToolsEnabled
      ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
          maxAge: 50
        })
      : []
  ],
  providers: [...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {}
}

// environment
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  devToolsEnabled: true,
  ...
};
```

The environment.ts file will be overwritten by your specific environment file at build time with this flag:

`ng build --configuration=<<environment>>`

Comment: Ok - so would be use a different `environment.ts` file for the production build with `production: true` and `devToolsEnabled: false` and then build with that for production?

Comment: Also I assume that we could install the plugins as dev scoped npm dependencies and angular could read the `package.json` and see whether that's the case, and automatically exclude such dependencies based on that info.  Do you think that's a good idea?

Comment: exactly, here is good article about the usage of different environments

Comment: to your second comment: 
Yes, you could add it as a DevDep, but I doubt that it is worth the effort to implement a automized solution

Comment: Cool - I think you may have forgotten to link the article?

Comment: https://blog.angularindepth.com/becoming-an-angular-environmentalist-45a48f7c20d8